# Scalajs & scala ZIO

Tags: scala, scala.js, zio

Does scala.js work with scala ZIO?
I'm looking to use scala ZIO with scala.js I only know how to use scala ZIO in normal apps does anyone know how to use it with scala.js?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not supported yet, but is planned before releasing ZIO 1.0, as stated in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz-zio/issues/401). ZIO 1.0 should be released sometime in the next months.

Comment: @NaseemMahasneh If the above answers your question, consider *accepting* the answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but here is an example of ScalaJS + Zio: https://github.com/sb-dev/zio-scalajs

It uses Webpack to make the compiled javascript available in the index.html file.